# Min Max function bugs in illustrator javascript/extendscript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Can someone explain why the following code returns different results in Safari/Javascript and Illustrator/ExtendScript?

In my tests the browser version of this seems to work as expected. Illustrator not so much. Is this a genuine bug? Or just an issue with ExtendScript (Adobe's Javascript implementation for Creative Suite apps) and the apply method?

```
function testMinMax(){
    var testArray = [2,1,7,3,6,7,8,23,45,26,13,9];

    function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
      return Math.min.apply(Math, numArray);    
    }

    function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
      return Math.max.apply(Math, numArray);
    }

    alert ("min [" + getMinOfArray(testArray) + "] of " + testArray);
    alert ("max [" + getMaxOfArray(testArray) + "] of " + testArray);

    // Expected Values:
    // min [1] of 2,1,7,3,6,7,8,23,45,26,13,9
    // max [45] of 2,1,7,3,6,7,8,23,45,26,13,9

    // Illustrator Scripting returns the following values
    // min [1] of 2,1,7,3,6,7,8,23,45,26,13,9
    // max [9] of 2,1,7,3,6,7,8,23,45,26,13,9   
}

// Call the test case
testMinMax();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. After I saw your post (the only thing I could find), I had to come up with this workaround;

```
var varSourceArray=[varSource_R, varSource_G, varSource_B]
varSourceArray.sort()

varSource_Min = varSourceArray[0];
varSource_Max = varSourceArray[2];
```